# Convert object to custom list

Tags: c#

I get a custom list from a `webservice`, I need to convert the custom list in a custom list created on the client.

I get the value of the webservice like this:

```
List<object> list = ((IList<object>)service.EventosDoDia()).ToList();
```

Now I need to put the value of the list in my custom list,

```
List<Evento>
```

How do I transform my object in this list?

Class `Eventos`

```
public class Eventos
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string texto { get; set; }
    public string comentarios { get; set; }
}
```

see the print debug, look at the values ​​that I have in my list
http://i50.tinypic.com/14mt1ti.png

Comment: what is that `object` looks like?

Comment: why not stay with list<object>? i don't think there is a need of type-exactness when displaying items of a list.... also Http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @andy guess it's spanish. Evento should be a custom class, while `EventosDoDia()` should return a IQueryable of `Eventos` who fulfil the condition they happened this day

Comment: Eventos is custom class, EventosDoDia() is a return webservice

Comment: I don't agree that this question should have been closed. The one marked as duplicate was not answered and is closed as "Not a real question". It's obvious that English isn't this persons first language so give him a break.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Linq;

var eventList = list.Cast<Evento>().ToList();
```

Comment: I tried but the error debugging and saw that que  eventList = null

Comment: [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) won't ever return `null`. There ought to be a mistake on your side. If your `list` is `null`, you will get an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like

```
var list = service.EventosDoDia.ToList();

var event = new List<Evento>();
list.ForEech(c => 
               {
                 event.Add(new Evento()
                           {
                             id = c.SomeIdFromService,
                             logo = c.SomeForLogoService
                             //TOPO: Some Properties
                           };
               });
```

Comment: Looks like that's what you're talking about, most did not understand that part of (c.SomeIdFromService and c.SomeForLogoService).

Comment: oh yes.. it just an example from the properties of `service.EventosDoDia`, you can just replace that from the actual proprieties you have :)

Comment: mhmm.. i updated my answer, if you really have a List of `EventosDoDia` you can see the properties of the `EventosDoDia`

Comment: EventosDoDia is the return from webservice

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<iClubs.ws.Eventos>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<iClubs.Eventos>'

Comment: i apologize, try to debug you project.